# Динамическая подгрузка классов по требованию

Tags: php

Добрый день хэшкодовцы, с наступающим Вас!!!

Копаюсь направлении автозагрузки классов, и то ли день не тот, то ли выспался плохо, понимание приходит с большим трудом. Мог бы кто-нибудь объяснить как сейчас на php реализуют динамическую подгрузку классов с помощью **spl_autoload_register()**.

Нашел следующий пример, но за неимением полной картины и отсутствия опыта использования пространства имен что-то не особо понимаю как объявлять классы Class1 и Class2 и можно или нельзя использовать исключения для автозагрузчика (на php.net сказали, что крайне нежелательно)?

```
class ClassAutoloader {
        public function __construct() {
            spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));
        }
        private function loader($className) {
            echo 'Trying to load ', $className, ' via ', __METHOD__, "()\n";
            include $className . '.php';
        }
    }

    $autoloader = new ClassAutoloader();

    $obj = new Class1();
    $obj = new Class2();
```

Comment: Пока могу сказать, что классы должны быть в директории с файлом загрузчика с именами классов.

То есть

 - loader.php
 - Class1.php
 - Class2.php

должны быть в одной директории. если так не нравится - в методе loader исправьте путь)

Comment: При объявлении классов что-нибудь изменяется? И использование это пол беды, хотелось бы знать как отрабатывет метод loader(кто его вызывает). И другие классы должны быть дочерними от autoLoader-а?

Comment: насколько я помню про autoload, это что-то вроде геттера. При создании класса (см. последние строки в вашем скрипте) класс ищется среди объявленных и если не находится, то следует вызов `ClassAutoloader::loader($classname)` и следом еще одна попытка объявления. Соотв-но, если она обламывается - скрипт падает с "Class not found".

То есть, вы просто кидаете классы в одну директорию и считаете, что все файлы включены.

Comment: Спасибо, кое-что уже понятно, а как быть с исключениями, когда например хочется просканить на предмет наличия классов несколько директорий?

Comment: Хм, в исключениях не вижу смысла. Просто просканьте, ну а если класса нет, значит в любом случае нормальная работа скрипта дальше невозможна, надо падать)